# How to make something appear after position:fixed; element?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

So I have a fixed element that will be a picture that will vary in height, and I want to add text after it, but outside that div.

[Example](http://hayneniam.tumblr.com/) of what I need changed.

Because I need that hover not to include text, and if I put text outside the div of the picture, it naturally, end up at the beginning of the sidebar. So I need some solution to make it follow the picture, but without specifying height where it should start, because as I said height of the image will vary since I want to be able to put whatever image I want.

Comment: I find this question to be a bit unclear.  Can you explain in different words?

Comment: Well, if you look at the example you will see the text after the picture, but when you hover the picture or text, menu will appear from both sides. I need that not to include text. For text to be a separate element and to always be after the picture no matter what its height.

Comment: So add the hover effect only to the img element in question? (If necessary, wrap it into another div)

Comment: But `#SidebarImg img:hover #RightSlide {...}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of current structure:

```
div#SidebarImg
  div.LeftSlide
  div.RightSlide
  img
  div#Description
```

Make something like:

```
div#SidebarImg
  div#SlidesContainer
    div.LeftSlide
    div.RightSlide
    img
  div#Description
```

The #Description div is now outside of the *image-and-slides* part, so now the `#SlidesContainer img:hover #RightSlide {...}` selector should work

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but I don't really know how, when I try what you suggested slides don't appear at all.

Comment: The rest should be done with css - some attributes should be moved from #SidebarImg to new div#SlidersContainer. But what about moving div#Description outside divSidebarImg? That should help too

Comment: Actually, I got around this... You helped a lot. Thank you so much!